# How to express BNF using Lisp?

Tags: lisp, racket, grammar, bnf

I want to express a grammar rule that is written in BNF using Lisp. 
here is the rule. It is important to note that non-terminals are represented in capital letters and the terminals are represented in small letters:

```
A -> a A b
```

I tried to use the define function of lisp to define that grammar. However when I use a define function Lisp obliges me to specify the body of the function that I defined.

```
   #lang racket
   (define (A a A b B)())
```

However if I fill the body with whatever like:

```
   #lang racket
   (define (A a A b B)("Hello World"))
```

I don't get any error.

My question here is whether I should specify something in the body that will help me define other rules of the grammar, for example should I specify in the body of `A` the rule for the non terminal `B`? 
If that `define ()` function is not the right one to use, what other function(s) would help me represent that BNF grammar using Lisp?

Comment: Is [ragg](https://github.com/jbclements/ragg) relevant?

Comment: What part of ragg do you mean?

Comment: I thought perhaps you could either (a) just use it, or, (b) if you want to build this yourself, look at its implementation for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something here, but it seems to me that you want to represent an EBNF as a piece of data. If this is the case, you could simply use an s-expression.

Something like this, perhaps?

```
#lang racket

(define my-ebnf
  `((A (a A b))
    (Q (z z Q z))
    (T (A p Q))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is exactly what I want to reach. However, I tried giving to the prompt the ebnf for example a A b, so I can expect an A as an answer but I get the following error: 
> a A b
. . a: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition

How can I check if a pattern belongs to the ebnf usung Lisp?

Comment: I want to do processing on that language for example check if a specific formulation is part of the language or not?

Comment: yikes... that's a completely different question. You want to write a backtracking parser? Are you trying to write it yourself, or use an existing one?

Comment: Thank you for understanding me right! Exactly, I am basically trying to write it myself. That would be very helpful if I find one and modify it. If not, I would love to know the basic data structures, or functions to use and how to use them?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at this classic, recursive descent parser:

http://www.cs.indiana.edu/eip/compile/scan-numlist.ss

The example consists of a lexer for a small Scheme subset.
It was used for he the Scheme compiler workshop in 1996.

http://www.cs.indiana.edu/eip/compile/